# Split time (HHMMSS) into three different columns

Tags: python, pandas

```
Column A
22:55:12
```

Column A is currently in (Object), Sample to convert it into Datetime format

```
Expected Output:
Hour Minute Seconds
22   55     12
```

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhyM8.png)

Comment: df[['hour','minutes', 'seconds']] = df['time'].str.split(' : ',expand=True)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas.Series.str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split) with the expand flag set to True.

Then assign the new columns back to your DF.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ["22:55:12", "18:26:23", "12:58:48", "16:41:06"]})

df[['hour', 'minutes', 'seconds']] = df['time'].str.split(':', expand=True)

# For Display
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       time hour minutes seconds
0  22:55:12   22      55      12
1  18:26:23   18      26      23
2  12:58:48   12      58      48
3  16:41:06   16      41      06
```

---

You can also create a separate DataFrame if you don't want the old data:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ["22:55:12", "18:26:23", "12:58:48", "16:41:06"]})

new_df = df['time'].str.split(':', expand=True)
new_df.columns = ['hour', 'minutes', 'seconds']

# For Display
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
  hour minutes seconds
0   22      55      12
1   18      26      23
2   12      58      48
3   16      41      06
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it ok?

```
import pandas as pd
# Think this dataframe as your main DB
database = pd.DataFrame({'time': ["15:38:00", "02:20:00", "19:27:07", "18:50:09"]})
for time in database['time']:
    h, m, s = map(int, time.split(':'))
    print(h, m, s)
```

Result:

```
15 38 0
2 20 0
19 27 7
18 50 9
```

Comment: want to loop through the whole 'time' dataframe into three different features

Comment: I don't know exactly. But I changed the code a little. @Lokesh

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to convert it to Datetime

```
from datetime import datetime

timestr = "22:55:12"
timedt = datetime.strptime(timestr, "%H:%M:%S")

print(timedt)
print(timedt.strftime("%H\t%M\t%S"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert the column to a datetime object and then use the [`.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) accessor to grab the hour, minute, and second:

```py
dates = pd.to_datetime(df["Column A"])

df["Hour"] = dates.dt.hour
df["Minute"] = dates.dt.minute
df["Second"] = dates.dt.second
```